# postgresql physical read/write per process

Tags: linux, postgresql

I'm building my own application (on CentOS 6.2 and pgsql-9.1.6) that shows the amount of disk read/write KB per postgresql backend process.

I found a useful [SITE](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt?id=HEAD#l1305)  though, I didn't understand exactly what is different between `rchar` and `read_bytes` and I'm not sure when `cancelled_write_bytes` happens.

Should I take `cancelled_write_bytes` into my consideration?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: I'd consider using the perf tracing api, or instrumenting PostgreSQL using an `LD_PRELOAD` library that records writes.